# Right methods of copying strings with malloc

Tags: c, string, malloc

I want to copy the string “Best School” into a new space in memory, which of these statements can I use to reserve enough space for it

A. `malloc(sizeof(“Best School”))`

B. `malloc(strlen(“Best School”))`

C. `malloc(11)`

D. `malloc(12)`

E. `malloc(sizeof(“Best School”) + 1)`

F. `malloc(strlen(“Best School”) + 1)`

I am still very new to C programming language so I really am not too sure of which works well. But I will love for someone to show me which ones can be used and why they should be used.

Thank you.

Comment: Since the purpose of learning is to think for yourself, please [edit] your question and provide your reasoning for each of the possibilities. Beside of having erroneous and good options, this is opinion-based.

Comment: Are you per chance having a C test in school right now...? Should have studied harder in that case.

Comment: I'll close this as a duplicate since the top answer in the target answers the question.

Comment: @Lundin IMO it is a bit more general question not only about the string literals

Comment: @0___________ The dupe target explained what a null terminator is. The OP of this post doesn't know, hence their confusion. Also, we really don't need to answer questions that look as if they are potentially asked by someone trying to cheat on a live exam...

Comment: Ask yourself a few questions (and answer them!): How much space do you need?  What is the value of `sizeof(“Best School”)`?  What is the value of `strlen("Best School")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literal strings in C are really arrays, including the null-terminator.

When you use [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) on a literal string, you get the size of the array, which of course includes the null-terminator inside the array.

So *one* correct way for a literal string would be `sizeof("Best School")` (or `sizeof "Best School"`).

You can also use [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen). If you don't have a string literal but another array or a pointer to the first character of the string, then you *must* use `strlen`. But now you have to remember that `strlen` returns the length of the string *without* the null-terminator. So you need to add one for that.

So *another* correct way would then be `strlen("Best School") + 1`.

Using [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) is almost never correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `sizeof` id limited to only this one case (string literal). Ti will not work if you will have a pointer referencing the string. Before you start to be more proficient in C language and "feel" the difference between arrays and pointers IMO you should always use `strlen`

Example:

```
char *duplicateString(const char *str)
{
    char *newstring = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    if(newstring) strcpy(newstring, str);
    return newstring;
}
```

In this case, sizeof(str) would give the size of the pointer to `char` (usually 2, 4 or 8) not the the length of the string referenced by the `str`

Answer (score 0):

Addition to the above answer, malloc(12) will also work since it include the length of the literal string plus the null terminator.